# How to regain access to dedicated backup drives in Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Our company has found the need to move from Window Sever Backup (WSB), and I would like to, for the lack of better words, reclaim the drives I was using for the backups.  WSB has made these drives "dedicated" and now theses drives will not show up.  I have checked to see if they are recognized by the   bios, the drive’s manufacture utility software, Disk Management and even installed the drives into other machines.  I'm at a loss, and I would appreciate some useful help.

Comment: Have you deleted all the existing backups and catalogs? Have you also uninstalled WSB?

Comment: Remove the drive as a backup location in WSB.

Comment: You'll have to forgive me...I'm use to Veritas.  I'm not seeing any options to remove the drives as a backup location.  After using more robust backup programs I'm feeling very limited on options here.

Comment: do they show up in diskpart ?

Comment: A slow way would be just zero-wipe the drives with dban, or your favorite tool.

Answer (score 1):

Stop/Disable the backup in the WSB management console. This will "release" the drive back to the operating system.